# error "expression result is unused" in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, syntax-error, c++14, clion

I have some code like:

```
double calculate_self_term(double area)     {
    double corr = 2.0 * sqrtpi / sqrt(area);
    return calculate_reciprocal(0, 0, 0) + self_energy + corr;
}
```

where `self_energy` is defined at the beginning:

`#define self_energy -2.0 * alpha / sqrtpi;`

Then I got an error:
**expression result is unused** for the variable `corr`.

Comment: It's because of the `;` at the end of the macro.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your IDE - post the text of compiler error messages.

Comment: I think it is because of the semicolon `;` at the end of your self_energy macro which ends the current expression.

Comment: @NeilButterworth He's not getting a compiler error, he's just getting a warning in the IDE.

Comment: @Barmar If the IDE can diagnose it, so should the compiler.

Comment: OMG! I am soooo stupid!!!! Sorry guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use macros for such things.

With your definition:

```
#define self_energy -2.0 * alpha / sqrtpi;
```

Your code substitutes to:

```
return calculate_reciprocal(0, 0, 0) + -2.0 * alpha / sqrtpi; + corr;
```

At which point the issue should be obvious - you have this `+corr` expression statement, after your `return` statement, which is doing nothing.

If you didn't use the macro, you wouldn't have run into such an issue. Don't use macros for such things. This should probably just be a function:

```
constexpr auto self_energy(double alpha) { return -2.0 * alpha / sqrtpi; }
// ...
return calculate_reciprocal(0, 0, 0) + self_energy(alpha) + corr;
```

Comment: The problem isn't with using macros, it's with mistakenly ending the macro with `;`.

Comment: @Barmar The specific problem may be ending the macro with `;` The broader problem is using the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon in the macro

```
#define self_energy -2.0 * alpha / sqrtpi;
                                        ^^^
```

and write it like

```
#define self_energy ( -2.0 * alpha / sqrtpi )
```